# The CREATE DATABASE statement failed. The primary file must be at least 4 MB to accommodate a copy of the model database

Tags: sql, installshield, sql-server-2012-express

I'm creating an installer using InstallShield. During this install, it first installs SQL Server 2012 express (which is successful) and the second part is where I create a new database using another .exe that handles all the deploy scripts.

When creating the database using the installer, I receive the following error in the event viewer:

> "The CREATE DATABASE statement failed. The primary file must be at least 4 MB to accommodate a copy of the model database."

I can fix this by going in and reducing the size of the model database to 3 and it works. However, I can't really take that path because these are supposed to be unattended installations.

After the database is set up, but before I try to run the deploy scripts, then I can use the same create statement through SQL Management studio.  It then creates the database just fine.

Here is the script used to create the database.

```
CREATE DATABASE [Database1] ON  PRIMARY ( NAME = N'Database1', FILENAME
= N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.INSTANCE1\MSSQL
\DATA\Database1.mdf' , SIZE = 4096KB , FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) LOG ON 
( NAME = N'Database1_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL 
Server\MSSQL11.INSTANCE1\MSSQL\DATA\Database1_log.ldf' , 1024KB , 
FILEGROWTH = 10%)
```

As you can see, the size is 4MB and the Model Database properties say that its size is 4MB.

[image: Model Size Property]

Comment: Since you are installing a new instance of SQL Server 2012 Express, are you building a large-enough PRIMARY file group?  Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but it sounds like you are testing your script on an already existing instance of SQL Server, which would probably have a large-enough PRIMARY file.  How big is the PRIMARY file on the newly created instance?

Comment: I only have one instance and that is the INSTANCE1 that i specified the name for. That is the same instance I connected to using SMSS and ran the script on. The script executed under Master